# Byte-wise testing memory buffers for equality

Tags: swift, optimization

I'm writing a Swift app that needs to test large in-memory data buffers for byte-identical equality, as fast as possible. Surprisingly, there appears to be no specific framework or API for this, so the function I've written is currently of the form:

```
func buffersAreEqual(lhs: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>, 
                     rhs: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>, byteCount: Int) -> Bool
            
    let bufferPointerLHS = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: lhs, count: byteCount)
    let bufferPointerRHS = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: rhs, count: byteCount)
    
    for bytePair in zip(bufferPointerLHS, bufferPointerRHS) {
        if bytePair.0 != bytePair.1 {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    return true
}
```

(In fact I'm rebinding the Int8 buffers to Int64s to reduce the iterations, but the above is the simplified gist of my solution.)

I feel there must be a better solution than this iterative byte-banging; is there some lower-level approach I could use (for instance some kind of Accelerate or SIMD memory comparison), which would provide unambiguously better performance than my current approach?

This is for a macOS app, and there's no absolute requirement for it to be written in Swift if there's a faster approach using C, but a Swift solution would be nice.

Comment: Wnat about `memcmp(lhs, rhs, byteCount) == 0` ?

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the suggestion -- looks like memcmp's implementation is just as naive as mine though. But it's neater to use it, at least.